# Magento 2 Error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2.2, configurable-product-options

I am overriding magento configurable.js to my theme and adding some function.i am getting an error of 403 forbidden url.any one can you please help me to short it out.

```
 _specifictionContent:function (productMainID) {
        var productMainID = parseInt(productMainID);
       //alert(productMainID);
       var url_data = "<?php echo $block->getUrl( 'getsku/sku/index/' ); ?>";
        if(typeof productMainID == 'number'){
            $("#common_specification").hide();

            jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url_data,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id:productMainID},
                    showLoader: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#config_simple_specification").html(response);
                    }
                });
        }
    },
```

In above function i am passing simple product id of a configurable product.
and want to send it to my controller and get back some product specification to show/hide in configurable product page.

My controller file is like this.

```
<?php
namespace t5media\Quote\Controller\Sku;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
)
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{   
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); echo $id;
    //echo $this->_productRepository->getById($id)->getSku();  
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();

        $remove_set = array("hm_mostpopular_prod_featured","hm_most_popular_product","quote_only");//This 
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
            $atr_code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            $user_defined = $attribute->getIsUserDefined();//user defined attribute or Magento default attribute
            if($user_defined==1){ //if user defined attribute it will show
                $attr_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($atr_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                if($attr_value !='' && !in_array($atr_code, $remove_set)){ //if have value and not in to removed attribute list it will show to table.
                    ?>
                    <li><span class=""><?php echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel();?></span> <span class=""><?php echo $attr_value;?></span></li>
                    <?php 
                } //END of IF
            } //END of IF
        } //END of foreach  

}
}
```

If i access the url `http://127.0.0.1/tork/getsku/sku/index/?id=611` i can get the result.

[image]